# How do I make my radio buttons checked

Tags: php, html

I have a table, that generates rows dynamically. I have used radio buttons for each row. I want the radio button to be checked even after I click my submit button.
This is body of my table:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><h3>Date<h3></td>
          <td><h3>Status<h3></td>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <?php for($i=$start;$i<$end;$i++)
          { 
            $add=$ARRAY[$i]['source_address'];
            $Status=$ARRAY[$i]['Status'];
            $total=$add.$Status;
          ?>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="radio" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"/></td>
      <?php
      echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['escl_date'].'</td>';
      echo'<td>'.$ARRAY[$i]['escl_status'].'</td>';
      ?>    
     </tr>
     <?php }?>
      </tbody>
</table>

<input type="submit" name="details" value="details" />
```

How Can I make the radio button selected even after clicking on submit button? Please help me.

Comment: Could you post a little more of the context of your code?

Comment: I have edited my code have a look @seanlevan

Comment: Check out my answer, it still applies @lillyshk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct HTML attribute you are looking for is `checked`.

*Note to other answer: `readonly` is not necessary, nor is it what OP is asking for.*

Since you're doing it in PHP, let's say you're passing something with an HTML markup `name` of `foobar`, as follows:

`<form><input type="radio" name="foobar"></form>`

To make sure that the value is retained even after it is submitted, you could add a code like this (`get` or `post` depending on your purpose):

`<form><input type="radio" name="foobar" <?php if(isset($_GET[foobar])){ echo "checked"; ?>></form>`

This is to make sure that it would be checked if the name was passed in the form.

Note that this is just an example.

Comment: What did you try? Could you post the code, and could I try to help you? @LillyShk

Comment: <input type="radio" name="ID[]" <?php if(isset($_GET['ID[]'])){ echo "checked";} ?> value="<?php echo $total; ?>"/>

Comment: But you should be using `POST`, not `GET`. Your form is in POST. For example, `$_POST['ID'][0]`. @LillyShk

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="radio" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"   <?php echo $_POST['ID'][0]==$total ? 'checked':'';?>  />`? @LillyShk

Comment: I used like this:$_POST['ID[$i]'] but its not working :(

Comment: Does it output any error code? What do you think is wrong? @LillyShk

Comment: Cool! How did you fix it? @LillyShk

Comment: I used this $_POST['ID'][0] instead of $_POST['ID'][$i]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, You need a condition to check with *reference* value and add `checked` attribute.

Here your reference value is your POST of `ID` value.  Add this into your `radio` tag `<?php echo $_POST['ID'][0]==$total ? 'checked':'';?>`

```
<input type="radio" name="ID[]" value="<?php echo $total; ?>"   <?php echo $_POST['ID'][0]==$total ? 'checked':'';?>  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works:

```
<input type="radio" checked>
```